How is ROC AUC calculated for a Support Vector Machine?
My understanding is that a support vector machine (SVM) finds a hyperplane that separates two classes from each other. During training, there can be some amount of error allowed so that some classes can be on the wrong side of the hyperplane. But during scoring, we output a prediction as class1 if it is above the hyperplane and class2 otherwise.
ROC is calculated by plotting the (False Positive Rate, True Positive Rate) of a model's predictions at different thresholds.
How is ROC calculated for an support vector machine? If the hyperplane is fixed, then how can there be a threshold to adjust?
